# how could someone make a c# incremental compiler like Java?

Tags: c#, incremental-compiler

Years ago someone asked [why c# doesn't allow incremental compilation like Java](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/why-doesnt-c-allow-incremental-compilation-like-java-t3054253.html). El Skeet said it is to do with Java outputting .class files rather than assemblies.

Now that its 2011 and groovy things like the Mono compiler-as-a-service have been released, what would need to be done to make an incremental compiler for c#?

edit: to everyone banging on about how this isn't a problem, here's a quote from Jon Skeet from the thread I linked to :

> Are you suggesting you never find yourself waiting for a build? Even 15 
>   seconds? If a build takes 15 seconds and you want to build 20 times in 
>   an hour (which I certainly do with TDD) that means I'm wasting 5 
>   minutes. Taking a 5 minute break is one thing - that's a good way of 
>   relaxing etc - but being held up for 15 seconds 20 times can be very 
>   frustrating. It's not long enough to do anything useful (other than 
>   maybe sip a drink) but it's long enough to irritate.
>
> I suspect two factors contribute the level of annoyance I feel which 
>   others apparently don't:
>   1) TDD really relies on a faster turnaround
>   2) When working with Java in Eclipse, such delays are very rare

Comment: May be because no one really needs it?

Comment: People need it. Believe you me.

Comment: Why? Please provide a scenario. I can't think of any... which might just mean, that I have no fantasy ;-)

Comment: Add a space character to a .cs file in asp project. Hit build. Wait 184 seconds before build finishes.

Comment: @mcintyre321 I develop for .net 5 days a week several years and never felt that I need incremental compilation. So I am not sure which people are you talking about. BTW if you define your assembly structure well result will be similar to incremental granularity.

Comment: @mcintyre321 Get an SSD. Seriously.

Comment: Solutions: 1) hardware upgrade, or 2) refactor project to be smaller

Comment: @mcintyre321 move it to separate dll and compile only it.

Comment: Have SSD/i5/8GB RAM, company is spending time refactoring, still a problem, these are not answers to my question.

Comment: @mcintyre321 you asked wrong question. Why didn't people go to Mars? Because no one (except for space romantics) needs it.

Comment: @mcintyre321 take a look at my updated answer

Comment: @Andrey: are you suggesting no one would benefit from faster compile times?

Comment: @jalf please read first sentence of my answer. It gives my understanding. In edits I showed answers from Mono's Architect that are similar to my thoughts.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it was not done then there is only one reason for it: efforts to do it are higher than possible benefits.

Microsoft will definitely not do it because costs are too high: .net code lives in assemblies and no one will change it. And yes, assemblies prevent class-by-class incremental compilation. No one will stop using assemblies.

And here is my answer why no one needs it. You can distribute your classes that constitute single project among several assemblies and compile them one by one. It is actually incremental compilation but not as fine-grained as class-by-class incremental compilation. And when your architecture is properly designed assembly level incremental compilation is sufficient.

**Edit**: Okay, I downloaded Mono C# compiler to take a look it is possible to make it incremental. I think it is not very hard. Basically it does following steps: 1) Parse files 2) Compile 3) Create assembly. You could hook somewhere after types are compiled and save then into some sort of intermediate files. Then recompile only changed ones. So it is possible, but looks like it is not high-priority issue for Mono team.

**Edit 2**: I found [this interesting thread](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-devel-list/2006-July/019366.html) where people discuss Incremental compilation for Mono C# compiler. It is rather old but key explanation might be still valid:

> Lexing and parsing normally are very
>   fast and depend only on the size of
>   the code being parsed. Semantic
>   analysis is normally the most time
>   consuming step as loading referenced
>   assemblies and sifting around the huge
>   metadata to resolve symbols and types
>   is really the meat of the compiler,
>   also, new "compiled" code is
>   "appended" to this metadata/AST what
>   increases the complexity of resolving
>   symbols over time. Emission of code is
>   done in memory first so it is fast.
>   Saving to disk is slow but depends on
>   emitted code size.
>
> For incremental compiling, caching the
>   metadata, would make everything very
>   fast, as normally very little would be
>   changed from one compilation to the
>   other. But gmcs would have to
>   invalidate only part of the
>   metadata/AST, what **it wasn't built
>   for**.

**Edit 3**: C# compiler had `/incremental` option in v1.0 and v1.1, but it was [removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379563%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> The /incremental flag found in the 1.0 and 1.1 version of the C# compiler is now considered obsolete.

**Edit 4**: Miguel de Icaza gives clear answer ([1](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-devel-list@lists.ximian.com/msg08637.html), [2](http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-devel-list@lists.ximian.com/msg08648.html)) why Mono Compiler will not be incremental:

> There are many, many more places where
>   GMCS was just not designed to work on
>   an edit-and-continue scenario.
>
> If someone wants to make this their
>   thesis subject, that is fine with me,
>   but the amount of changes are too
>   large in too many areas.  I do not
>   even want to bother enumerating them.
>
> The reason I did not list things is
>   because they will be everywhere in the
>   compiler.  Am sure you will run into
>   them as soon as you try them out ;-)

So he considers it to be a task huger than for one man's thesis. And Mono has much more outstanding and actual tasks.

Comment: How do assemblies prevent class-by-class incremental compilation?  It seems to me that the limitation comes from the design of the toolchain - csc.exe outputs completed assemblies, so there's no separate linker.  Is there anything, aside from the effort involved, preventing someone from writing a C# compiler that produces object files which then have to be packed into assemblies using a separate linker?

Comment: @Sean U there is one actually: al.exe ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c405shex(VS.80).aspx ) but C# compiler doesn't use it.

Comment: Sure, but as you say none of the compilers that come with Visual Studio really rely on it; they compile straight to assemblies.  My question is, is there any reason why csc.exe HAS to output complete assemblies?

Comment: This is a good answer, but I'm going to wait before accepting as I would really like to know if the Mono compiler-as-a-service feature would permit this

Comment: @mcintyre321 compiler as a service can handle it, because it can build code in smaller chunks. The problem is that a) you will have to maintain all references and resolve them by yourself b) it is not suitable for building whole applications.